# PowerMockito VerifyStatic not working in 2.0.0-beta5

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am getting an issue using powermockito (2.0.0-beta5) to verify a static method was called a certain number of times when I call a different (also static) method.  The classes are prepared for test at the top of my test file The relevant code snippet is:

```
mockStatic(Tester.class);
when(Tester.staticMethod(anyString(), anyString())).thenAnswer(new FirstResponseWithText());
OtherClass.methodThatCallsTesterStaticMethod("", "", "", false, "");
verifyStatic(Tester.class, times(3));
Tester.sendFaqRequest(anyString(), anyString());
```

`FirstResponseWithText` is a class that extends `Answer` that controls the order of responses.  I've used that elsewhere and it works fine.

I get the following error on the `verifyStatic` line:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() is of type Class and is not a mock!
Make sure you place the parenthesis correctly!
See the examples of correct verifications:
    verify(mock).someMethod();
    verify(mock, times(10)).someMethod();
    verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).someMethod();
```

What is the proper way to pass the class to `verifyStatic`?  All the examples I can find online are for pre-2.x.x releases where `verifyStatic` did not take a class parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the PowerMockito version is not the problem. I tested the following code with versions

- 1.7.3,
- 2.0.0-beta.5 (your version),
- 2.0.2.

**Application classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q52952222;

public class Tester {
  public static String sendFaqRequest(String one, String two) {
    return "real response";
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q52952222;

public class OtherClass {
  public static void methodThatCallsTesterStaticMethod(String one, String two, String three, boolean four, String five) {
    System.out.println(Tester.sendFaqRequest("A", "B"));
    System.out.println(Tester.sendFaqRequest("C", "D"));
    System.out.println(Tester.sendFaqRequest("E", "F"));
  }
}
```

**Test classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q52952222;

import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class FirstResponseWithText implements Answer {
  @Override
  public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
    Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
    String methodName = invocation.getMethod().getName();
    return methodName + " called with arguments: " + Arrays.toString(args);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q52952222;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ Tester.class })
public class MyTest {
  @Test
  public void myTest() {
    // Tell PowerMockito that we want to mock static methods in this class
    mockStatic(Tester.class);
    // Stub return value for static method call
    when(Tester.sendFaqRequest(anyString(), anyString())).thenAnswer(new FirstResponseWithText());
    // Call method which calls our static method 3x
    OtherClass.methodThatCallsTesterStaticMethod("", "", "", false, "");
    // Verify that Tester.sendFaqRequest was called 3x
    verifyStatic(Tester.class, times(3));
    Tester.sendFaqRequest(anyString(), anyString());
  }
}
```

So if this does not work for you and your Maven or Gradle dependencies are also okay, the difference is maybe in your `FirstResponseWithText` class. Maybe you want to show it so we can all see what kind of magic you do in there. As you can see from my sample code, I had to make several educated guesses because you only share a little snippet of test code and not [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like you should. This way I can only speculate and actually I do not like to because it might be a waste of time for both you and myself.